# What does .push.bind do?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn coding in Javascript and came across this question and have a few questions.  What does results.push.bind(results) do in this question? Please see question below:

Suppose getData is a function that takes a query object and returns a promise for the result of the query. Suppose also that someArrayOfQueries is an array of query objects. Explain what would be printed by the following code and why:

```
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {  
    var results  = [];  
    queries.forEach(doQuery);  
    return results;  
    function doQuery(query) {    
        getData(query)      
            .then(results.push.bind(results));  
    }
}
function log(value) { 
    console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries(someArrayOfQueries).forEach(log);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc., and try to do the work**. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work, although really what's required here is just research.

Comment: `.bind` is a method that allows you to attach a context to a method. That probably sounds like gibberish to a newcomer. In basic terminology when you have an object with a method you can call that method on any other object as long as you specify using `.bind` or `.apply`, etc. It's an important concept when working within JavaScript, especially with intermediate topics such as currying/closures/etc. so it's worth looking at. I would suggest searching StackOverflow, the MDN (mozilla developer network), and other resources to more thoroughly research before posting here though.

Comment: Nothing would get printed at all (except maybe for the error message that an array (`results`) doesn't have a `.then()` method. Notice that even [the `push`ing of results won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) - promises are asynchronous! The proper implementation is  `function runMultipleQueries(queries) { return Promise.all(queries.map(getData)); }`

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, unlike in other Object Oriented languages, the variable `this` is quite complicated and can be changed many times.

When working with arrays, the function `push` takes the array it is called "on", and puts a new element to the end of it. In this case, the push function knows what array it is working on by reading the `this` variable.

Imagine this example code:

```
var myDataStructure = {};
myDataStructure.value = 0;
function addOneToValue() {
  this.value += 1;
}
myDataStructure.addOne = addOneToValue;
myDataStructure.addOne(); // here - the variable `this` == myDataStructure
```

However, if you call the function `addOneToValue` with the code `addOneToValue()`, the value of `this` is not in fact `myDataStructure`. It is undefined, or a global object like `window`.*

To manually force `addOneToValue` to always use `myDataStructure` as the `this` value, you can do the following:

```
addOneToValue = addOneToValue.bind(myDataStructure);
```

Now you can safely call `addOneToValue()`, since the `this` value was *bound* to `myDataStructure`.

In your code, `runMultipleQuery` is passing the function to another handler, who will not call the function like `results.push`. That means when the function is called, `push` will again have an uncertain `this` value. However, by calling bind, we can ensure that `runMultipleQuery` calls the `push` function and forces `this` to be the `results` variable.

Comment: thank you for the detailed example  I now understand what .bind() does!

Comment: No problem! If I answered your question, press the green checkmark to mark the correct answer. When you spend more time on StackOverflow, you will be able to upvote good answers and downvote bad ones as well.

Answer (score 3):

What `results.push.bind(results)` does is it forces the method call of `push` to use the scope of `results`.

**TLDR;**
`results` is an Array.  `results.push()` is a call to `Array#push`, but by passing the function `results.push` directly to the Promise `Promise#then` it will be called within a different scope.

That is, the keyword `this` will reference a different object.

By using `bind` (e.g. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), the scope will be "bound" to a specific Object.

The reason for this is because JavaScript is a prototype language, rather than an object-oriented language.

Answer (score 1):

> What does .push.bind do?

Returns the `.length` of the array, when called

```js
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
  var results = [];

  return Promise.all(queries.map(doQuery));

  function doQuery(query) {
    return Promise.resolve(query)
      .then(results.push.bind(results))
  }
  
}

function log(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries([10, 20, 30]).then(log);
```

Note, that as astutely observed and alerted to by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815479/what-does-push-bind-do/46815798?noredirect=1#comment80580589_46815798), the pattern `.then(results.push.bind(results))` actually returns the `.length` of the array.

One solution which still includes the use of the pattern is to chain a second `.then()` to get the `.length` returned by previous `.then()` and return the element of the array by subtracting `1` from the value and using bracket notation

```js
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {
  var results = [];

  return Promise.all(queries.map(doQuery));

  function doQuery(query) {
    return Promise.resolve(query)
      .then(results.push.bind(results))
      .then(len => results[len - 1]);
  }
  
}

function log(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries([10, 20, 30]).then(log);
```

though creating `results` array is not necessary when using `Promise.all()`, which returns an array of values

---

`.forEach()` alone will not await the previous result of `getData()` call, `results` will probably be an empty array at `runMultipleQueries(someArrayOfQueries).forEach(log);`

Use `Promise.all()` and `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`, `return` the `Promise` from `getData()` call

```js
function runMultipleQueries(queries) {

  return Promise.all(queries.map(doQuery));

  function doQuery(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(query)
      }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
    })
  }
  
}

function log(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

runMultipleQueries([1,2,3]).then(log);
```

Comment: Can you explain why the first snippet logs `[1, 2, 3]`? I suspect it does not do what you expected, or what the OP expected.

Comment: @Bergi _"Can you explain why the first snippet logs `[1, 2, 3]`?"_ Not sure what you mean? What did you conclude OP is expecting?

Comment: I concluded that he expected the results of the `getData` promises to be passed to the final `log`. That's not what's happening here, and I suspect you didn't notice. That's why I'm asking whether you can explain where those numbers come from.

Comment: @Bergi Are you referring to the fact that `Promise.all()` returns a new array? And that `results` array is not necessary? Or that `results` array is actually not returned from the function?

Comment: No, I'm referring to the origin of those numbers (`1`, `2` and `3`). Please walk me through. Or try to pass other numbers and see whether you can explain the result

Comment: @Bergi Good catch. `.push()` returns `.length` of the array which is the value returned from `.then()`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that catch. You might want to adjust that part of your answer.

Comment: @Bergi See updated post. Will include your astute observation at Answer; though not certain the description will provide the adequate weight of your alerting the erroneous omission.

Comment: @Bergi See updated post. If the description is lacking, do advise.

Comment: @gues271314 I now understand why it wouldn't return an results because of async and sync.  But why does it return the length of the array?  I thought array.push(array) would return the values of the array not the length?

Comment: @user8796981 `var arr = []; console.log(arr.push())`, _"3. Let len be ToLength(Get(O, "length"))."_, _"11. Return len."_ [22.1.3.17 Array.prototype.push ( ...items )](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.push)